# Handling swipes outside the controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

My goal is to not write the swipe detection code in all of my controllers. So what I did was create class: "Swipes" like so:

```swift
class Swipes{

private var leftController: String
private var rightController: String
private var target: UIViewController

init(leftController: String, rightController: String, target: UIViewController){
    self.leftController = leftController
    self.rightController = rightController
    self.target = target
}

func initLeftRightSwipes(){
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    target.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    target.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("swipe detected")
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(rightController) 
            target.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            print("Swiped down")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(leftController)
            target.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
            print("Swiped up")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And in my view controller:

```swift
let swipe = Swipes.init(leftController: "popularID", rightController: "newID", target: self)
swipe.initLeftRightSwipes()
```

However this does not work. I get the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error because the the selector is pointing to a function which is not in the controller. It it possible to handle the swipes outside of the controller? I kept researching but found nothing.

What I also tried was to set the target in the UISwipeGestureRecognizer to self but the view in view.addGestureRecognizer to the view of the current controller. That also failed.

Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: U can subclass the VC to something like `ParentViewController` with that gesture reccognization then all other VC is the subclass of that `ParentViewController`, then it will all execute that method as u want, if u want to continue use your code above, i think u will have to create and pass the delegate to tell the class to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a parent SwipeViewController like:

```
class SwipeViewController: UIViewController{

    private var leftController: String?
    private var rightController: String?

    func addSwipes(leftController: String, rightController: String){

        self.leftController = leftController
        self.rightController = rightController

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    }

    func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("swipe detected")
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(rightController!)
                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
                print("Swiped down")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(leftController!)
                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
                print("Swiped up")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now In the View Controller where you want swipe make in subclass of `SwipeViewController`:

```
class ViewController: SwipeViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     //Here simply call addSwipes Function:

       self.addSwipes("view1", rightController: "view2")
    }
```